# ¿Cómo puedo ver el valor de una calve, de un diccionario que esta dentro de un diccionario? (Python3.9.2)

Tags: python

¡Ey gente!, he estado aprendiendo Python desde hace poco y tengo una pregunta: ¿Cómo puedo ver el valor de una clave, de un diccionario que esta dentro de un diccionario?. Esta es la forma en la que yo creía que se era, pero da TypeError:

```
Diccionario = {"Diccionario": {"Uno": 1, "Dos": 2}}
print(Diccionario["Diccionario"["Uno"]])
```

Comment: Casi, en realidad lo que intentas es algo así:  `Diccionario["Diccionario"]["Uno"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer iterando en las llaves con `dict.keys()`

```py
Diccionario = {"Diccionario": {"Uno": 1, "Dos": 2}}
for e in Diccionario["Diccionario"].keys():
    print(e)
    print(Diccionario["Diccionario"][e])
```

El método `keys()` nos trae las llaves o claves del diccionario. si queremos acceder al elemento hacemos `Diccionario["Diccionario"][e]` (debajo del `print()`)

Pero si solo queremos el valor de las claves mejor es utilizar `.values()` en lugar de `.keys()`, de esta forma

```py
Diccionario = {"Diccionario": {"Uno": 1, "Dos": 2}}
for valor in Diccionario["Diccionario"].values():
    print(valor)
```

También podemos hacerlo con una compresión de diccionario:

```py
Diccionario = {"Diccionario": {"Uno": 1, "Dos": 2}}
valores = [v for v in Diccionario["Diccionario"].values()]

print(valores)
```

**resultado**

```
[1, 2]
```

Si queremos ambos valores, pues iteramos con `.items()`, esto nos devuelve una tupla, la cual en este caso vamos a almacenarla como tal.

```py
Diccionario = {"Diccionario": {"Uno": 1, "Dos": 2}}
for item in Diccionario["Diccionario"].items():
    print(item)
```

**resultado**

```
('Uno', 1)
('Dos', 2)
```

De igaul forma se puede hacer con una compresión de lista:

```
Diccionario = {"Diccionario": {"Uno": 1, "Dos": 2}}
items = [item for item in Diccionario["Diccionario"].items()]
print(items)
```

**resultado**

```
[('Uno', 1), ('Dos', 2)]
```

Comment: Hasta donde veo, eso no me permite almacenar el valor de las claves, solo almacena las claves en una lista

Comment: lo dije en mi explicacion solo haz `Diccionario["Diccionario"][e]`, pero ahora edito mi respuesta añadiendo algo mas

Comment: Listo, respuesta editada

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo, me ha funcionado :D

Comment: muchas gracias a ti por contribuir a la comunidad :)